# terminal processes exited/closed but anaconda keeps running

Tags: jupyter-notebook, terminal

I haven't opened my terminal or anaconda in MONTHS possibly this whole year and now every time i reopen it i have to exit it?? I'm  able to exit the process with CTRL Z (I'm using a macbook).

Is there a command to make thisNOT be happening every time i open terminal?

I'm  able to exit the process with CTRL Z (I'm using a macbook).  I close the terminal and reopen hoping to not see that again to no avail. it didn't use to open on this so i must've changed some setting through Jupyter i don't recall?